# How to find for a string in html code

Tags: php, string

I am trying to find a string from a html section

Example

```
<div class="container" data-id="Youtube" style="height:100%;width:100%;border:none;">
<div class="inner"></div>
```

Generally we find a string using

```
if(strpos($string,"YouTube") !== false)
```

but for a sample test i am trying to store the html code into a php variable

```
$string="<div class="container" data-id="Youtube" style="height:100%;width:100%;border:none;">
    <div class="inner"></div>";
```

when i try to find for a **youtube** in $string , It always returns false(does not exist)

Can anyone help me to find the string in a html code
Thank you

Comment: youtube !== Youtube, use a case insensitive method (stripos in your example)

Comment: You should probably surround your entire string in single quotes...

Comment: Also, be careful with your quotes. You may want to open your variable with single quotes, so that you can use double quotes in the HTML

Comment: I guess it's time for the [***"You can not parse HTML with regex"***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) question again !

Comment: Now we will vote for any question, just randomly yea? what's wrong with the question? why -1?

Comment: Well I didn't downvote, but I am guessing that the fact the given "sample test" would immediately give a parse error *may* be why people do not think the OP has actually tried it

Comment: @Anigel Yea but anyways this is far better than other, it has code, it is on point, it is formatted, downvote breaks their confidence

Comment: Parse error !! no i am testing on my localhost , No error found

Comment: @Ramarajudantuluri  Orly?  php -r '$string="<div class="container" data-id="Youtube" style="height:100%;width:100%;border:none;">'
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in Command line code on line 1

Comment: And I am comparing Youtube!==Youtube but not youtube, i need exact match

Comment: @Anigel Ohh my mistake. i have to include a ; and i would have wrapped the entire string in single quote. Sorry. But i tried the correct way on my machine

Comment: This is where it gets confusing, if you had given the actual code you had tried on your machine then most of the people would not have wasted their time giving you comments and answers about a problem that only existed in the sample code you gave above, which was not the same as your actual code

Comment: Ya, will take care before posting a question. I just intended to point out how i tried and not the syntax like missing semi-colon in my context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this simple test for you....it's working on my localhost:

```
<?php

    $string="<div class='container' data-id='Youtube' style='height:100%;width:100%;border:none;'><div class='inner'></div>";
    $search = "Youtube";
    if(strpos($string, $search) !== false)
    {
        echo "Found";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Not found";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Ya, I tried this already. a user will enter this html code through a form, and it will be stored in database and used later.So i think i must mention the user that html attribute values must be single quoted. right?

Comment: Yes @Rama ....your html should looks like my $string var...if you try this code, it's works....if you change the $search value to "Zebra", it echo "Not found" ...

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
if(strpos($string,"Youtube") !== false)
```

if this is your problem use `stripos()` for case insensitivity.

Answer (score 3):

use single quote around string here

```
$string='<div class="container" data-id="Youtube" style="height:100%;width:100%;border:none;">
<div class="inner"></div>';
```

also use `stripos` for case-sensitivity

```
if(stripos($string,"YouTube") !== false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your html with simple quotes :

```
$string = '<div class="container" data-id="Youtube" style="height:100%;width:100%;border:none;">
    <div class="inner"></div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `if(strpos(strtolower($string),"youtube") !== false)`

I always use strtolower() to avoid similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath + dom objects just like

```
class CeiXML extends SimpleXMLElement
{

    public static function asHTML($xml)
    {
        $ele = dom_import_simplexml($xml);
        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
        $element = $dom->importNode($ele, true);
        $dom->appendChild($element);
        return $dom->saveHTML();
    }

}

$html = '
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="Youtube" style="height:100%;width:100%;border:none;"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
     </body>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($html);
$tags = $xml->xpath('//body/div[@id="Youtube"]');

$string = CeiXML::asHTML($tags[0]);
```

I hope that help you